# Proof of Set containment by definition of Equality of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have come to solve the following question:

prove by the definition of Equation Of Sets that if $A\cup B = B$ then $A \subseteq B$.

What I did is to follow exactly the definition of Equation of Sets, meaning I tried to prove both directions of equation:

1. $A\cup B\subseteq B$ $=>$ $A \subseteq B$
2. $B\subseteq A\cup B$ $=>$ $A \subseteq B$

I managed to prove (1) easily, but had problems with (2) and even could find a contradiction for (2).
My contradiction is for A={1,2,4} B={1,2,3}

Above-mentioned makes me wonder if overall it's possible to prove. maybe I do something wrong.

Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\cup B=B$ and suppose $A\not\subseteq B$, then there is an element $a \in A$ where $a \not \in B$ which is a contradiction since $B=A\cup B$

Comment: This is exactly what I thought at the beginning. But I had to prove the claim using the definition of equality of sets. the definition notes that there's equality between sets A and B, if and only if A is included in B and B is included in A.
But by this way I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: But in this case you're not proving equality, you're assuming the equality of the union and then proving that $A\subseteq B$. So assume $A\cup B \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A \cup B$

Comment: You're 100% percent right! somehow I forgot that I assume the first part of iff and prove *only* the second one. thanks for putting my mind corretly